# How to Specify a Compound key in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework-4, poco, code-first, northwind

I have a quick question about setting up the mappings between `[Order Details]`, `[Products]` and `[Orders]` in the Northwind datbase.

`[Order Details]` has no primary key, and looks like this

```
[Order Details]
OrderId (int)
ProductId (int)
...
```

So my question is how do I (and can I) set up my `OrderDetails` class to work like this?

```
public class OrderDetails
{
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public Decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public Decimal Discount { get; set; }
}
```

My data context looks like this

```
public class NorthwindDb : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrderDetailsConfiguration());
    }

    public static void InitializeBecauseOfThatWeirdMetaDataThingThatIDontUnderstandYet()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<NorthwindDb>(null);
    }

}
```

And My `OrderDetailsConfiguration` (empty because I don't know what I'm doing)

```
public class OrderDetailsConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<OrderDetails>
{
    public OrderDetailsConfiguration()
    {
        //HasKey(x => x.Order.OrderId);
        //HasKey(x => x.Product.ProductId);
    }
}
```

Any hints or ideas would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you would have to explicitly put in the PKs and FKs inside *OrderDetails* class:

```
public class OrderDetails 
{        
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public Decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public Decimal Discount { get; set; }
}
```

Then with the following code you can specify the PKs for *OrderDetailsConfiguration* class:

(Please note that in *Northwind* database both *OrderID* and *ProductID* are PKs for *OrderDetails* table).

```
public class OrderDetailsConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<OrderDetails> 
{
    public OrderDetailsConfiguration() 
    {
        HasKey(od => new 
        {
            od.ProductID,
            od.OrderID
        });
    }
}
```

And also you can use *RecreateDatabaseIfModelChanges* strategy to force your database to be recreated every time you change the class model:

```
Database.SetInitializer<NorthwindDb>(
        new RecreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<NorthwindDb>());
```

The interesting point is that once you made these changes EF will automatically infer the FKs from *OrderDetails* class and create the relationships to *Orders* and *Products* table on OrderID and ProductID based on the [***Conventions for Code First:***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/efdesign/conventions-for-code-first)

> Code First will infer that any property named `<navigation property name><primary key property name>` (i.e. ProductsProductID), `<principal class name><primary key property name>` (i.e. ProductProductID) or `<primary key property name>` (i.e. ProductID), with the same data type as the primary key, represents a foreign key for the relationship. If multiple matches are found then precedence is given in the order listed above. Foreign key detection will not be case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Morteza.  I guess the next question is how to keep the order and product id's protected, but I'll do some digging on that before asking here.

Answer (score 1):

Mark key fields with [Key] attribute. You will need to add [Column(Order = x)] in case of compound keys, x = 0, 1, 2, ...
Numbering can start from any number 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx