# More than one record is updated EF-Linq C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following table:

[image]

I have several arrays, where I will scroll if the data match to decrease its amount:

```
//DISMINUYE CANTIDAD DE CASILLER
        public void disminuyeCasiller(string[] codParte, string [] rolls, double[] cantResta)
        {
            int size = codParte.Length;

            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                string parte = codParte[i];
                string rol = rolls[i];
                double valorRes = cantResta[i];

                using(var ctx=new ModelContext())
                {
                    Casiller updateRollo = ctx.Casillers.Where(x => x.cod_parte == parte && x.rollo == rol).First();
                    double newValue = updateRollo.cantidad - valorRes;
                    updateRollo.cantidad = newValue;
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
```

According to what this code does, it is first to know what size the arrangements are (all the arrays will have the same size), create a `for` and get the amount if the `rollo` and the `cod_parte` match, to that amount you recover in this case `300` will be subtract what arrives in `cantResta` for example `100.50`, once subtraction is assigned in the place it was, save the changes and repeat if necessary, until there everything is fine.

I am passing this data:

```
codparte[]=new array{"11155"};
rollos[]=new array{"RT0102"};
cantRest[]=new array{100.50};

//Size and data can be different -only a example
```

at the end of `cantidad` with `rollo RT0102` in the table I should stay like this: `199.50`, the problem is that update both records and it looks like this:

[image]

Why also update `RT0103` when this row is not being selected? What am I doing wrong in the sentence? (can be a problem in the future cuz many `rollos`has the same information)

**SCREENSHOT BREAKPOINT**

[image]

Comment: "I am passing this data..." Are you sure? The data types of the arguments do not match the data types of the parameters, which are arrays.

Comment: @JohnWu I'm assuming that the data passes in each of the arrays, I'll edit the question

Comment: Do you have a primary key defined, and have you marked it as such in EF?

Comment: @JohnWu Only `cod_parte` is a primary key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Only cod_parte is a primary key

This is the problem.

A primary key must be unique, but in your case you have more than one record with the same `cod_parte`. So it's not even a key, let alone primary.

When you call `SaveChanges()`, the EF will generate a SQL statement with a WHERE clause that contains the primary key and nothing else, assuming that the primary key will identify exactly one record. That assumption is false, because your "primary key" isn't really a key.

For this table you need a compound primary key of at least `cod_parte` and `rollo`, or, as Robert has noted, a genuine synthetic primary key.

See also [How to specify a compound key in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158859/how-to-specify-a-compound-key-in-entity-framework-code-first).

Comment: `[Key][Column(Order = 0)]public string cod_parte { get; set; }` and  `[Key] [Column(Order = 1)]public string rollo { get; set; }`  works, thanx

Answer (score 0):

Please check your passing data , if only pass `codParte=111555,rolls=RT0102,cantRest=100.50` then it won't update `RT0103`.

ex:

```
public class Test{
    public static void Main(){
        disminuyeCasiller(new[] { "111555"}, new[] { "RT0102"}, new[] {100.50});
    }

    public static void disminuyeCasiller(string[] codParte, string[] rolls, double[] cantResta)
    {
        int size = codParte.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            string parte = codParte[i];
            string rol = rolls[i];
            double valorRes = cantResta[i];
            Console.WriteLine($"parte {parte}/rol {rol}/valorRes {valorRes}"); //Result:parte 111555/rol RT0102/valorRes 100.5
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the problem, I never pass `RT0103` but it update that record

Comment: why are you sure? chrome web tool check passing data? debug check?

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot of breakpoint, idk if something with this line `Casiller updateRollo =...` that affectes the code